# Securing a simple REST Service with Basic Authentication

Tags: rest, security, basic-authentication

I have a very simple REST Service and I wan't to test a simple basic authentication.

I changed the web.xml in order to configure a specifix REST Endpoint for basic auth:

```
<security-constraint>
      <display-name>Restricted access</display-name>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/healthCheck</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
        <description>Only authenticated users can access this area</description>
        <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

After that it seems to work, if I call the service with SOAP UI I get 401 unauthorized.

After that I added a basic auth (user and pass) in SOAP UI, but the behaviour doesn't change. I always get a 401 unauthorized.

I think I missed something. Can some help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your SOAP UI client is trying to do SPNEGO authentication which isn't supported.
Did you try an ordinary curl to check if the basic auth works?
`curl -u username https://my.endpoint.com`